# Can I configure the VS.NET 2008 IDE to use gcc as a compiler?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gcc

Can I configure the VS.NET 2008 IDE to use gcc as a compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a make file project, in a make file project you can define what to run in build, rebuild and clean.
You will have limited support for IntelliSense but must of functions will work as usual.